# Fine Alphabet in number in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have a table like this :

```
CREATE TABLE [Mytable](
    [Name] [varchar](10),
    [number] [nvarchar](100) )
```

i want to find [number]s that include Alphabet character?

data must format like this:

```
Name | number
---------------
Jack | 2131546
Ali  | 2132132154
```

but some time number insert informed and there is alphabet char and other no numeric char in it, like this:

```
Name | number
---------------
Jack | 2[[[131546ddfd
Ali  | 2132*&^1ASEF32154
```

i wanna find this informed row.
i can't use 'Like' ,because 'Like' make my query very slow.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updated to find all non numeric characters

```
select * from Mytable where number like '%[^0-9]%'
```

Regarding the comments on performance maybe using clr and regex would speed things up slightly but the bulk of the cost for this query is going to be the number of logical reads.

Comment: i can't use 'Like' ,because 'Like' make my query very slow, There is another way?

Comment: Possibly clr and regular expressions might be marginally quicker. Have you actually tested it?

Comment: anything you do will table scan, this type of query should only be a one time cleanup and not run repeatedly

Comment: yes, i tested it in table that have 1,000,000,000 row and it very slow. Another point is that you query never find '[]$%#@#%...' char!

Comment: @KM. but my query run repeatedly

Comment: @cool-i3oy `'[]$%#@#%` are not characters in any alphabet I am familiar with. Did you want to find non numeric characters?

Comment: @cool-i3oy - Why do you need to calculate this same information repeatedly? Assuming there is some legitimate need for this then you could possibly add an indexed persisted computed column with the formula `case when number like '%[^0-9]%' then 1 else 0 end`

Answer (score 0):

A bit outside the box, but you could do something like:

1. bulk copy the data out of your table into a flat file
2. create a table that has the same structure as your original table but with a proper numeric type (e.g. int) for the [number] column.
3. bulk copy your data into this new table, making sure to specify a batch size of 1 and an error file (where rows that won't fit the schema will go)
4. rows that end up in the error file are the rows that have non-numerics in the [number] column

Of course, you could do the same thing with a cursor and a temp table or two...